# PHP Where to keep software version?

Tags: php

All,

Where can I keep my software version in a PHP web application? I inherited an application that has versions in about 500 different files (for example it might say "Super Program v1.0 written by blah blah" at the bottom of each page, and I have to change it to 2.0, so whenever I need to update the version, I use Eclipse's search function and go to town. Globals seem the right place, but then I find that my variable doesn't get propagated unless the .PHP file is included, etc.. Any ideas?

Edit: I'm also open to any tools that are used to help me handle this, I haven't tried using any outside utilities or eclipse extensions to swap out the variables, I'm trying to get an idea for what everyone else is doing.

Thanks,
Dan Chase

Comment: " I'm trying to get an idea for what everyone else is doing." not bothering with version numbers at all .. or using svn\git

Comment: If at all then you have one central "meta data array" or similar that you can cite values from where required. But honestly: what is the point in visuallizing the program name and version on each view of a program? Just remove that stuff! It annoys everyone, including you, so get rid of it.

Comment: Well the versions are for the customer to know they are running the latest, I'd like to rip it out but my client wouldn't go for that.

Comment: Why should anyone be interested in a version of a web application? A web application is upgraded whenever the service provider wants to. Except if it is a local install, and in that case people typically know what they installed, since they installed it. Take a look at the "owncloud" project for a good example. They show the software verson at one place where it makes sense and nowhere else: in the adminstrative settings page.

Comment: Good point, I could remove it from "most" locations, and the customer would like the fact that it takes me less time to make code changes. That would still leave a few, wouldn't be so bad.. So I feel you solved my problem as a whole, but I'm still curious where to store such a variable for easy access if not a file,etc.. is everyone just not doing it?

Comment: Ok confirmed my customer wants the version at the bottom of all reports. So back to the root of my question, how do I get a variable like that to go across the whole project?

Comment: I *think* most version-control tools have some sort of macro facility that could do this for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use, Subversion, GIT or something similar for a start. This will automatically track versions meaningfully so you can go back and forward through versions with confidence. This is a really good practice to get into, especially with 500 files to work with.

To add the revision number into code, first replace all references with a constant. Then use a build tool like phing, ant or similar to obtain the latest revision number from the repository and assign it to the constant in a config file.

This means that the revision name displayed by you code always refers back to an easily obtainable version of the code at any time.

If you use something like Git which does not have incremental revision numbers, you can work around it by using tagging with appropriate names and putting the tag name into the constant which is displayed instead.

Answer (score 2):

If you're using composer to manage your dependancies, you can include the version number within `composer.json`. [It's a built it part of the schema](https://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#version).

```
{
    "version":"1.0.0"
}
```

You can then load `composer.json` and parse it with `json_decode()` to get the version number:

```
<?php
$composerJson = file_get_contents('composer.json');
$assocArray = json_decode($composerJson, true);
$version = $assocArray['version'];

var_dump($version);
?>
```

outputs:

> string(5) "1.0.0"

Comment: This would be the way that all of the php cool kids do it now. Prior to git, hg, and dvcs in general, people used the svn keyword functionality to replace version markers on commit

Answer (score 0):

Eclipse has the ability to find/replace across the entire project: http://www.avajava.com/tutorials/lessons/how-do-i-do-a-find-and-replace-in-multiple-files-in-eclipse.html

Comment: Thanks but that's currently what I'm doing. I also thought of putting "// VERSION" so I don't accidentally grab the wrong thing, or maybe having a staging directory where I have a script change !!VERSION!! afterwards and copy to a packaging directory..?